# Convert factor levels into the column names without changing the structure of the data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am doing a fairly easy job in `R` to convert the factor levels into column names.

Let `tmp` be a data.frame:

```
 tmp <- data.frame(x=gl(2,3, labels=letters[24:25]),
                   y=gl(3,1,6, labels=letters[1:3]), 
                   z=c(1,2,3,3,3,2))
> tmp
  x y z
1 x a 1
2 x b 2
3 x c 3
4 y a 3
5 y b 3
6 y c 2
```

My purpose is to make levels in `y` column into column names and put 1 in the corresponded column like below:

```
x   y   z   a   b   c
x   a   1   1   0   0
x   b   2   0   1   0
x   c   3   0   0   1
y   a   3   1   0   0
y   b   3   0   1   0
y   c   2   0   0   1
```

Note that what I need is different from `dcast` or `spread` function in the R package `reshape2` and `tidyr`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `mtabulate` from `qdapTools`

```
cbind(tmp, qdapTools::mtabulate(tmp$y))
#  x y z a b c
#1 x a 1 1 0 0
#2 x b 2 0 1 0
#3 x c 3 0 0 1
#4 y a 3 1 0 0
#5 y b 3 0 1 0
#6 y c 2 0 0 1
```

Or `cSplit_e` from `splitstackshape`

```
splitstackshape::cSplit_e(tmp, "y", type = "character", fill = 0)
```